# Study the convergence of the series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\frac{e^{it}}{2}\right)^{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, sequence-of-function

I would like to study the series

$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\frac{e^{it}}{2}\right)^{n}
$$

My idea is to first look at what can be said concerning any type of convergence:

$$
\forall{t}\in\mathbb{R},\forall n\in\mathbb{N} : \left\lvert\left(\frac{e^{it}}{2}\right)^{n}\right\rvert = \frac{1}{2^{n}}\left\lvert e^{itn}\right\rvert =  \frac{1}{2^{n}}(\cos^{2}(tn) + \sin^{2}(tn))^{1/2}=\frac{1}{2^{n}}\tag{1}\label{1}
$$

Thus we conclude that the series is absolutely convergent :

$$
\forall t\in\mathbb{R} : \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left\lvert\left(\frac{e^{it}}{2}\right)^{n}\right\rvert = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{2^{n}} = 2
$$

Which implies the pointwise convergence of the series and the normal convergence can also be deduced from $\eqref{1}$.

However, I did not succeed to find the limit, anyone has an idea ?

Thank you a lot

Comment: Your series is converging. The limit of the term $u_n$ is $0$ by the necessary convergence condition. Or you're looking for something else ?

Comment: @Hamdiken Thank you for your comment you are totally right ! And I am looking for a « concrete expression » of this series if it exists but I cannot figure out what it could be to be honest…

Comment: It’s just a geometric series isn’t it

Comment: The sum, assuming $0$ is in $\mathbb N,$ is $$\frac1{1-e^{it}/2}=\frac{2(1-e^{-it})}{5-4\cos t}$$,

Comment: Thank you a lot ! @ThomasAndrews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: I presume you know that
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty z^n = \frac{1}{1 - z}$$
for $\left|z\right| < 1$. Now consider $z = \frac{e^{it}}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you a lot !